# Как через приложение в андроиде отследить запуск других приложений с устройства?

Tags: java, android

Хотел написать приложение на андроиде, которое после запуска, создаёт журнал посещённых приложений на устройстве; но так и не нашёл, как можно отследить запуск того или иного приложения.
(единственное что нашёл - в настройках, при включённом режиме разработчика, можно увидеть список запущенных приложений)

Comment: отличный вопрос, мне кажется :)

Comment: Тема старая, лазейку давно прикрыли из соображений безопасности.  
Вот код, который работал до Андроид 5, насколько я помню. Теперь только для приложений уровня системы.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25722153/5479247